# Redirect website folders splitted into two different domains with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I am looking forward changing my oldomain.com and everything under its language folders oldomain.com/en and oldomain.com/it to newdomain.com  for the first and newdomain.it for the latter. I now need to take care of old links from olddomain with some 301 redirect in htcaccess of olddomain.

I think I may need something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^en(.*)$ newdomain.com$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^it(.*)$ newdomain.it$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am not sure if that's enough as I saw many variants around and I'm not expert. Should I take care of root olddomain also? Should I use Rewritebase or other code before/later?

I also stripped folders and html extenisons to new website page so I need to manually redirect any pages under any folder or subfolder to root of new domain without html.

Any help or hint in the right direction will be apprecieted.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need an `http://` in there, otherwise apache will mistake the `newdomain.com` to be a pathname:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^it/(.*)$ http://newdomain.it/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You don't need a rewrite base. As long as these rules are in the document root of your old domain (which is different than the document root of your new domain), you don't need anything else. If you need to redirect the root URL (e.g. `http://olddomain.com/`) to something, then you need to add it *after* those other two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

(or wherever you need to redirect it to).

Comment: Thanks for yoru reply! The old odmain is actually pointed to folder where I will need to put such htaccess code while d the newdomain will be pointed to the root, so I guess I will add Rewritebase to the beginning. Any hint how to use htaccess to redirect old pages under any folder to root and redirect any old page with html to non html ?